# Sharepoint 2013 Workflow Manager Disaster Recovery Certificate problem

Tags: 2013, restore, certificate, workflow-manager, service-bus

We want to restore a backup of our productive Sharepoint 2013 environment with all currently running Workflows on a new Sharepoint server. We found these manuals for ‘Workflow Manager Disaster Recovery’.

- [Disaster Recovery and Scope Restore in Workflow Manager 1.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj730570(v=azure.10).aspx)
- [Workflow Manager Disaster Recovery](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/biztalknotes/archive/2014/05/14/workflow-manager-disaster-recovery.aspx)

What we already did:

restored the needed databases (WFResourceManagementDB,
   WFInstanceManagementDB, SBGatewayDatabase, SBMessageContainer)

executed the cmdlets

1. Restore-SBFarm
2. Restore-SBMessageContainer
3. Restore-SBGateway
4. Add-SBHost
5. **Restore-WFFarm (FAILED!)** 
        *Token provider returned message: ‘`400`The
        namespace ‘WorkflowDefaultNamespace’ does not have a valid issuer
        that can be used to issue tokens. Add a valid issuer with a valid
        signature to the namespace.*

In the manuals we read, that we have to import the **ServiceBus certificate** from our productive environment. But we can’t find that certificate. With get-SBFarm we got the thumbprint, but there is no certificate on the server with that thumbprint.

Can anyone help? Is there maybe another way to do this?

Comment: check this blog for export and import certificate: http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm3.aspx

Comment: we already found this blog, but it doesn't solve our problem